# Find and Replace image src with the matching object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I'm trying to replace all src value with the matching key value, the text looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <br /><br />
lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem <img src="71521" alt="[ppm:alt id=17835]" height="426" width="638" /> ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
```

my object goes like the following:

```
    var mapObj = {
        '71505':'https://images.e12b64dd10dd068f0b4b6e8e9e5e/71505.jpg',
        '69451':'https://imagesf697987a167a07402549e86089d/69451.jpg',
        '71521':'https://images673d2cf1bfcb6fcc1d30f91/71521.jpg',
        ...
    }
```

i want to check if the src value is match with object key if so then replace all occurrences with corresponding value of the key, my desired output is

```
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <br />
lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
```

so far i have the following but it doesn't work

```
var res = row['Description'].replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, function(s, key) {
   return mapObj[key] || s;
});
```

I tried all solutions answered below, but i'm still not able to replace the src.

My html source coming from the excel sheet, i'm reading it like this

```
const rows = fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath,{encoding: `'binary'}).pipe(parser);`
```

Comment: Pretty straight forward problem but I do not see an attempt.

Comment: Why did `src="69451"` change to `src="https://imagesf697987a167a07402549e86089d/69451.jpg"` and not `https://imagesf697987a167a07402549e86089d/71513.jpg`?

Comment: I'm using nodejs, and when i do console.log in my terminal it doesn't change the src,  i'm also saving the result on a text file using fs.writeFile, still it doesn't change the src

Comment: @nick zoum thanks for pointing out, now correction is made

Comment: @sam You need to log the result of the `replace`. If you do `var a = test.replace()`. You should print `a` not `test`. Strings are immutable.

Comment: @ nick zoum i'm printing the log as you said, but still the same

Comment: i'm reading the html from a excel sheet using const rows = fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath,{encoding: 'binary'}).pipe(parser); will it matter?

Comment: @sam Make sure that the keys that don't get replaced exist in `mapObj`. Because that is probably the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188595/discussion-between-sam-and-nick-zoum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through all of the properties of `mapObj`, then you can find any element with `src` equal to that of the key by doing `document.querySelector("[src='71505']")`, after that just fix the `src`.

```js
var mapObj = {
  '71505': 'https://images.e12b64dd10dd068f0b4b6e8e9e5e/71505.jpg',
  '69451': 'https://imagesf697987a167a07402549e86089d/71513.jpg',
  '71521': 'https://images673d2cf1bfcb6fcc1d30f91/71521.jpg'
};

for (var key in mapObj) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`[src='${key}']`).forEach(item => item.src = mapObj[key]);
}
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <br />
<img src="69451" alt="[ppm:alt id=17835]" height="426" width="638" /><br /> lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem <img src="71521" alt="[ppm:alt id=17835]" height="426" width="638" /> ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
```

If the HTML is in string form and you don't want to parse it to HTML then you should replace all occurrences of `src="${key}"` and src='${key}' with that respective value from `mapObj`. Like so:

```js
var mapObj = {
  '71505': 'https://images.e12b64dd10dd068f0b4b6e8e9e5e/71505.jpg',
  '69451': 'https://imagesf697987a167a07402549e86089d/71513.jpg',
  '71521': 'https://images673d2cf1bfcb6fcc1d30f91/71521.jpg'
};

var fullText = `Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <br />
<img src="69451" alt="[ppm:alt id=17835]" height="426" width="638" /><br /> lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem <img src="71521" alt="[ppm:alt id=17835]" height="426" width="638" /> ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum`;

function changeText(text) {
  for (var key in mapObj) {
    text = text.replace(new RegExp(`src="${key}"`, "gi"), `src="${mapObj[key]}"`)
      .replace(new RegExp(`src='${key}'`, "gi"), `src='${mapObj[key]}'`);
  }
  return text;
}

console.log(changeText(fullText));
```

Comment: i want to use to with a string variable with holds the html data, how to replace document.querySelectorAll then? for example: var html = objectData

Comment: Will the second example I've added to my answer work for you?

Comment: @sam Do you also want to replace `src` that doesn't exist in `mapObj` with a default value? Because that is the only case where the `src` won't change

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the `keys` of `mapObj` using `forEach`. Each time replace `key` with value of key.You said *"the **text** looks like this"* So I consider you are asking for string

```js
let text = `Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <br />
<img src="69451" alt="[ppm:alt id=17835]" height="426" width="638" /><br />
lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem <img src="71521" alt="[ppm:alt id=17835]" height="426" width="638" /> ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum`


var mapObj = {
        '71505':'https://images.e12b64dd10dd068f0b4b6e8e9e5e/71505.jpg',
        '69451':'https://imagesf697987a167a07402549e86089d/71513.jpg',
        '71521':'https://images673d2cf1bfcb6fcc1d30f91/71521.jpg',
    }
Object.keys(mapObj).forEach(key => {
  text = text.replace(`src="${key}"`,`src="${mapObj[key]}"`);
})
console.log(text);
```

Comment: it doesn't replace the src :(

Comment: @sam it is working fine. Please check the snippet. I think its matching your expected output.

Comment: I'm using nodejs, and when i do console.log in my terminal it doesn't change the src, i'm also saving the result on a text file using fs.writeFile, still it doesn't change the src

Comment: @sam you will be making mistake somewhere else because code runs fine in the snippet

Comment: @MaheerAli To be honest it's possible your solution won't work if src is wrapped with `'` rather than `"`. But that's not the case, since mine doesn't work either. Good enough answer though, worthy of an upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the text in a container then use the querySelectorAll to get all the img. Then itertae that nodelist and replace the value with the corresponding result from the object

```js
var mapObj = {
  '71505': 'https://images.e12b64dd10dd068f0b4b6e8e9e5e/71505.jpg',
  '69451': 'https://imagesf697987a167a07402549e86089d/71513.jpg',
  '71521': 'https://images673d2cf1bfcb6fcc1d30f91/71521.jpg'
}

let txt = document.getElementById('content').querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(item) {
  let srcVal = item.getAttribute('src');
  item.setAttribute('src', mapObj[srcVal])
});
```

```html
<div id='content'>
  Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <br/>
  <img src="69451" alt="[ppm:alt id=17835]" height="426" width="638" /><br/> lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem <img src="71521" alt="[ppm:alt id=17835]" height="426" width="638" /> ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum my object goes like the following:
</div>
```

Comment: `You can wrap the text in a container` Easier said, than done in node